# Localized English launch image is not used

Tags: ios, image, localization, splash-screen, launch

Somehow I can't seem to get my localized launch image to work.
In the root of my project folder I have a localized Default@2x.png with both an English and a Dutch version.

Somehow the Dutch version is shown in all situations.

I have other localised files that work all right (Root.strings, Localizable.strings, InfoPlist.strings) when using English language.

I've looked up several related questions, but found no answer. Tried deleting the file all together en adding them again. After localizing the file I added the right picture to the right folder using 'Show in Finder' on the English version.

Other answers suggest that there's another copy of Default@2x.png somewhere that's in the way, but I can't seem to find one.
When I look at my project folder in Finder, some folders seem recursive (repeat themselves) though.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you showing the image *before* the application has determined what the locale is?

Comment: I'm referring to the standard, integrated xcode feature. The launch image that's immediately shown at startup of the app.

Comment: Other thing I tried: moving the different Default@2x.png files to their respective en.lproj and nl.lproj folders beneath Settings.bundle (where localized Root.strings also reside). Restarted XCode and rebuild app. To no avail...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Launch images can not be localized. See the [app programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12):

> All launch images (...) must reside in the top level of your app's bundle directory.

Comment: Have you got a reference for this?

Comment: It seems to me that I should be able to localize this. Other related questions and answers suggest so as well.

Comment: Solved by creating a global launch image and adding localization in a following splash screen.

Comment: App programming guide: `You can provide localized versions of your launch images if necessary.`

Comment: This answer is wrong. [Direct from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html): "You can provide localized versions of your launch images if necessary."